# set scope-value on click in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a toggle-thing in angular, I can't understand why it doesn't work.

I exepct that when i click the a-tag, the lower div should be displayed.

```
                <div>
                    <a href="#" ng-click='member = mathieu' class="mathieu">Lorem<br />Ipsum<span>Click for more</span></a>
                </div>

            <div ng-switch="member">
                <div ng-switch-when="mathieu">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this works. I have put together a quick plunkr to test it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/9JqxRNC9X5U2bJrkbxZ9?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.1"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <a href="#" ng-click="member = 'mathieu'" class="mathieu">Lorem Ipsum                <span>Click for more</span>
      </a>
  <br />
  <a href="#" ng-click="member = ''" class="mathieu">
    <span>Click to reset</span>
  </a>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch="member">
    <div ng-switch-when="mathieu">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`mathieu` needs to be a string value.  By itself it will resolve to `undefined`.
I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" ng-click="member = 'mathieu'" class="mathieu">Lorem<br />Ipsum<span>Click for more</span></a>
</div>

<div ng-switch="member">
    <div ng-switch-when="mathieu">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```